# How to assure that DNS requests are asked to a specific DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp

I have a set of virtual machines that I have to configure for an assignment. I configured a DHCP and a DNS server at my server machine. At the DHCP file the `option-domain-name servers` is pointing to the  IP address of my DNS server and `option-domain-name` has the name of my 'aulas' domain.

The thing is...I have another machine on my network with two interfaces. One of them is configured by my school dhcp server and the other interface is configured by my DHCP server (which works fine). For some reason when I make some DNS requests with `dig`, the DNS query goes to the school DNS server, which (of course) will not know this 'aulas' domain and will return no answers.  I'll put the link to my images [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWqNE.jpg).

Please understand that the reason why I used images is because of a network problem which is not allowing me to ssh into the server machine. The only way I have to access it is by spice which is very limited. I can't even copy the files to the web with ftp, because this `no route to host` error. I think this has nothing to do with the DNS problem... I would appreciate some feedback.

Comment: Try a [reverse SSH shell](https://www.howtoforge.com/reverse-ssh-tunneling) :). As for your problem - just make sure there is no other DNS-servers than yours in /etc/resolve.conf on your two-interfaced machine, the VMs should work fine as they are (provided they are not connected to the network with school dhcp)

Comment: I tried that before @Anubioz , and I have the same erro "port 22 : no route to host"

Comment: @Anubioz I do have the IP addr of school DNS Server on that file. Should I change it to mine?

Comment: Yeah, that would make your machine stop requesting unwanted DNS.As for reverse shells, your school probably forbids connecting to port 22, [try listening for shell on port 443](https://highon.coffee/blog/reverse-shell-cheat-sheet/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your /etc/resolv.conf to point to selected DNS. If this helps you will have to override your DHCP client setting to always use predefined DNS server not one supplied by DHCP server.

Also you will have to check routing and default gateway to make it possible to use both interfaces at the same time.

Comment: I made changes on /etc/resolv.conf and restarted the named service. This is the [named status](http://imgur.com/a/1l66C). Then the result of a DNS query is `connection timed out : no servers could be reached`

Comment: Ok, I solved those errors. I did what you told me to do. It works, but I need to always do that manually which is not what I'm trying to do. At the resolv.conf file the first nameserver is always the nameserver of my school. How can I change it?

Comment: For example http://askubuntu.com/a/63163/532534

Comment: Yeah that works @ESYSCODER ! I found that I can use supersede too. (If I add this option to dhclient.conf) However at my fedora 22 this file doesn't exist. I put a lot of time trying to find out where is that file is but I wasn't able to figure it out.